# An up-to-date equivalent for a slip of a boy / girl

Tags: idioms

Imagine a very young boy / girl is going to do something which is hurting your pride and putting you under a question mark. You get seriously annoyed and you want to prevent the child / very young boy/girl from continuing their action. An elder interferes and asks you about the reason behind your annoyance. You tell them:

> - **A slip of a boy / girl** is going to advise me.

Meaning that a not quite mature boy / girl who can be considered as a child is trying to advise me / tell me what to do etc.

Slip of a boy / girl was the only idiom I found for this concept in an old book of English language idioms in our own language. But according to this [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=fJQUAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&dq=%22a%20slip%20of%20a%20boy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhq9jg3PHRAhVJs1QKHVxpAroQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20slip%20of%20a%20boy%22&f=false) I got the fact that it is not much used these days. If so, then please let me know what can I use as an alternative here?

Comment: If you want to be nice about it, don't be mad or try to put down the person. You quietly say, "I'm sorry but I do not think you have quite enough experience/knowledge of the situation yet to know what we/I should do to handle it. But thank you for your opinion."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say

> I'm not about to take advice from a (mere) child.

In your hypothetical case, it is literally a child, but you could use this same expression sarcastically in a figurative sense to refer to an adult who is much younger than you are.

P.S. You should also be aware that there is a cultural gap here. The things which cause a loss of honor or shame vary from culture to culture.  Taking advice from a young child is not necessarily a shameful thing in the English-speaking world. It would depend on the circumstances. And age in modern English-speaking industrialized societies is not accorded the respect it receives in other cultures; there are no "village elders" in London, NYC, or Sydney.

Answer (score 1):

How about: neophyte? "This neophyte is trying to advise me" (Please note you will sound like an idiot if you admit this.)

> ne·o·phyte Google Dictionary
>
> noun a person who is new to a subject, skill, or belief. "four-day
>   cooking classes are offered to neophytes and experts"
>   synonyms: beginner, learner, novice, newcomer; More a new convert to a
>   religion. a novice in a religious order, or a newly ordained priest.
>   synonyms: novice, novitiate;

[Link synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/neophyte)

Comment: But what Cambridge Dictionary says is as below @Willo Rex: "someone who has recently become involved in an activity and is still learning about it". There is nothing to do with youth or the situation in which a young guy can be expressed by. Thank you anyway for being of help. :)

Comment: @A-friend maybe I do not understand. If a young person is new to a job, or an older person is new to a job /or a situation or a company, and they do not know or yet understand the entire situation -- they are a neophyte in that situation. Forgive me if I am misunderstanding, but aren't you saying this is about a person who probably should not be offering an opinion?

Comment: @A-friend  I understand now, you actually mean a child. I have no clue. I personally would use regualar language. "This kid is being impolite and I don't like it."

Comment: You're more than welcome @Willow Rex. I was exactly talking about a person who probably should not be offering an opinion because they are still very young and it can hurt your pride / honor? Perhaps as TRomano mentioned on his post, there is a deep cultural gap here.

Comment: @A-friend  it sounds like it. A co-teacher of mine was embarrassed by a student because she had pimples and he asked if she had measles. Still, the  response was just, "No."

Comment: Excellent. Short and to the point @Willow Rex. Thanks for being so attentive to details and another thank for helping me through all those tough and deep questions considering my lingual weaknesses to convey the matters in my mind.